# Clear(refresh) just one line but in two different tasks

Tags: c#, console, task, console-application

*When I run with 2 tasks, sometimes write datas in 3 (have to write always in 2 lines max)lines but idk why. Why is it do that? How can I fix it? Otherwise if I run with 1 task it is working well.* I tried to commented the code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace LifeBar
{
    class Program
    {
        public static readonly int FullHealth = 200;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

        Console.Write("What is the player ID: "); int playerId = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        //playerID is equals with the line where is writed

        var t1 = Task.Run(() =>
         {
             for (int i = FullHealth; i >= 0; i--)
             {
                 WhatDraw(i, playerId);
                 System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(150);
             }
         });
        //tasks.Add(t1);
        //var t2 = Task.Run(() =>
        //{
        //    for (int i = 200; i >= 0; i--)
        //    {
        //        WhatDraw(i, playerId + 1); (+1 cus I would like to write it to the next line)
        //        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
        //    }
        //});
        //tasks.Add(t2);
        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

*this is a line deleter*

```
public static void ClearCurrentConsoleLine(int playerId)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(playerId, Console.CursorTop);
        Console.Write(new string(' ', Console.WindowWidth));
        Console.SetCursorPosition(playerId, Console.CursorTop);
    });

}
```

*they are retunrnig with the lifebar*

```
/// <summary>
    /// Draw healt bar
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name = life> i </param>
    /// <returns>Health bar value</returns>
    static string DrawHealth(int life)
    {
        string health = String.Empty;
        if (life == 0) return "Frank dead";
        else if (life < 10) return "< 10";
            for (int i = 0; i < life / 10; i++)
            {
                health += " |"; // 1 amout of | equal with 10 health
            }

        return health;

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Draw armour bar
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="life"> (i)</param>
    /// <returns>Armour bar value</returns>
    static string DrawArmour(int life)
    {
        string armour = "| | | | | | | | | |";
        for (int i = 0; i < life / 10; i++)
        {
            armour += " |:|"; // 1 amout of |:| equal with 10 armour
        }
        return armour;
    }
```

*this is a depender*

```
    /// <summary>
        /// Health or Armour draw
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="fullLife">(i)</param>
        /// <param name="playerId">playerId</param>
        static void WhatDraw(int fullLife, int playerId)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, playerId);
            if (fullLife > 100)
            {
                double percent = fullLife / Convert.ToDouble(FullHealth);
                Console.WriteLine($"Frank ({Math.Round(percent * 100)})% " + DrawArmour(fullLife - 100));
                if (fullLife % 10 == 0)
                {
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(playerId, Console.CursorTop-1);
                    ClearCurrentConsoleLine(playerId);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                double percent = fullLife / Convert.ToDouble(FullHealth);
                Console.WriteLine($"Frank ({Math.Round(percent * 100)}%) " + DrawHealth(fullLife));
                if (fullLife % 10 == 0 && fullLife!=0)
                {
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(playerId, Console.CursorTop-1);
                    ClearCurrentConsoleLine(playerId);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You've got race conditions with setting the position and writing. You need some sort of synchronization primitive

Comment: For example event hendler?

Comment: No you need for example a lock. Something akin to `public static readonly object lockobject = new object(); /* later */ lock(lockobject) { Console.SetCursorPosition(); Console.Write(); } `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are hitting a **race condition**. Consider this order of events:

```
// Thread 1
/* a */ Console.SetCursorPosition
/* b */
/* c */ Console.Write

// Thread 2
/* d */ Console.SetCursorPosition
/* e */
/* f */ Console.Write
```

- `a` - Your first background task/thread runs and it sets the current cursor position
- `b` - It's not yet run the next command, so we can consider it "sitting" at line `b`.
- `d` - The second task sets the cursor position
- `c` - The first task writes to the console.

Well, the second task has changed the position!! All of the properties on the `Console` class are `static` so the first task is no longer writing to the location where *it* moved the cursor, but rather where the second task did.

The timing could be even worse; for example the cursor position could be moved *at the same time* (`a` and `d` execute *simultaneously*) or the second task could move the cursor position while the first task is writing (`d` executes *after* `c` starts but *before* it completes). If both lines `c` and `f` are invoked at the same time, you might expect garbled output.

Of course this is a dumbed down explanation that applies more *generally* when concurrency is involved. The `Console` class itself is synchronized to prevent some of these cases, but it does not/cannot when a single "operation" involves multiple commands (set position + write). This coordination is **up to you**.

We can achieve this easily with C#'s [`lock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement) statement (a shorthand for [`Monitor.Enter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.monitor.enter?view=net-5.0)/[`Monitor.Exit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.monitor.exit?view=net-5.0)) to ensure that our operations against the console cannot overlap:

```cs
private static readonly object lockobj = new object();

public static void ClearCurrentConsoleLine(int playerId)
{
    lock(lockobj) 
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(playerId, Console.CursorTop);
        Console.Write(new string(' ', Console.WindowWidth));
        Console.SetCursorPosition(playerId, Console.CursorTop);
    } 
}

static void WhatDraw(int fullLife, int playerId)
{
    lock(lockobj) 
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, playerId);
        if (fullLife > 100)
        {
            double percent = fullLife / Convert.ToDouble(FullHealth);
            Console.WriteLine($"Frank ({Math.Round(percent * 100)})% " + DrawArmour(fullLife - 100));
            if (fullLife % 10 == 0)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(playerId, Console.CursorTop-1);
                ClearCurrentConsoleLine(playerId);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            double percent = fullLife / Convert.ToDouble(FullHealth);
            Console.WriteLine($"Frank ({Math.Round(percent * 100)}%) " + DrawHealth(fullLife));
            if (fullLife % 10 == 0 && fullLife!=0)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(playerId, Console.CursorTop-1);
                ClearCurrentConsoleLine(playerId);
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Because we need to synchronize a *set of operations* against the `Console` we need to surround all of those operations in a `lock`. This will force any concurrent operations to wait until the resource is no longer in use. The lock is reentrant on the same thread so when `WhatDraw` has the lock it can safely call `ClearCurrentConsoleLine` without needing to wait.  Once you've locked access to a resource, best practices dictate that you should *always* lock around it, even for a single operation:

```cs
lock(lockobj) 
   Console.WriteLine("Single write");
```

I've also removed the `Task.Run` from the `ClearCurrentConsoleLine` method as it's pointless and adds unnecessary complexity, especially since we need to synchronize these operations. Remember that a `Task` is a promise to complete *at some later point*. By the time that actually happens you may not actually want to clear the line anymore! Better to just clear it synchronously when and as necessary.

Also note that `lock` cannot be used safely in `async` contexts and you'll need to use other synchronization primitives such as a [`SemaphoreSlim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim?view=net-5.0).

Comment: Thanks for the code and the explanation as well, it was very helpful